# The import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.catchException cannot be resolved in VSCode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, gradle, assertj

When I am trying to launch my Spring application using VSCode's [Extension Pack for Java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack) which has

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.catchException;
```

in one of the tests, I get `build failed` with the following message:

```
The import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.catchException cannot be resolved
```

However, when I press `Proceed`, the app works normally. I have

```
testImplementation group: 'org.assertj', name: 'assertj-core', version: '3.22.0'
```

in my `gradle.build` file and it also works fine if I compile it with `gradle build`. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to right-click the `build.gradle` file of your project and select `Reload Project`

Comment: This doesn't help me unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by cleaning the java language server cache. Was the first option provided by VSCode itself to fix the issue.